# (Blender Cycles 2.74) can´t see smoke on the render image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, gpu

i had created a simple scene and tryed a litle bit with smoke...
i can see the smoke in the solid mode, but not in the render mode...
[image]

i can´t also see the option GPU...[image]

Comment: You could try this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-zK7Bu8cAI

For GPU rendering you need a specific video card. Which video card do you have? For example NVIDIA is supported

Comment: Could you try connecting the **Color** output, rather than the **Fac** output, from the color attribute node to the Color input of the shaders? I've not yet tried setting up smoke manually in Cycles, but that's how the Quick Smoke connects it.